# Рисование эллипса

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, рисование

Как создать эллипс или точку на месте клика левой клавишей мыши, которые соединяются линией?

Эллипс каждый раз рисуется новый, а старый остается.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp = 700, 550

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, self.width(), self.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.paint = QPainter()
        self.paint.begin(self)
        self.paint.drawEllipse(3, 3)
        self.paint.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint

class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp = 700, 550

        self.pos = QPoint(120, 70)                                # +++

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600, 300, self.width(), self.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.paint = QPainter()
        self.paint.begin(self)
        self.paint.drawEllipse(self.pos, 100, 50)                # +++
        self.paint.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pos = e.pos()                                   # +++
            self.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPainterPath, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widthApp, self.heightApp = 700, 550

        self.pos = QPoint(120, 70)    
        self.posList = [QPoint(120, 70),]               # +

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600, 150, self.width(), self.height())
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.paint = QPainter()
        self.paint.begin(self)

        self.paint.setPen(QPen(QColor("blue")))
        self.drawLine(self.paint) 
        self.paint.setPen(QPen(QColor("red")))

        self.paint.drawEllipse(self.pos, 10, 10) 
###
        for p in self.posList:                   # +
            self.paint.drawEllipse(p, 10, 10)

        self.paint.end()

    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.pos = e.pos()                                   
            self.posList.append(self.pos)        # +
            self.update()

    def drawLine(self, qp):
        qp.drawLine(300, 10, 300, 200)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(100, 200)
        path.lineTo(300, 200)   
        qp.drawPath(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В моем случае, каждый раз элипс должен рисоваться новый,а старый остается. @S.Nick